# tikz get picture width and height in pixels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Below code can get picture width and height in pt, what's the right way to get width and height in pixel?

```
\documentclass[border=1pt,convert={outfile=\jobname.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
%https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Panthera_tigris_sumatran_subspecies.jpg
\newsavebox{\graph}\savebox{\graph}{\includegraphics{Panthera_tigris_sumatran_subspecies.jpg}}
\newlength\gh\setlength\gh{\heightof{\usebox\graph}}
\newlength\gw\setlength\gw{\widthof{\usebox\graph}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[draw] {\the\gw,\the\gh};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: pixel is display dependent hence TeX can't know what your display settings are

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108516/uncertain-about-dpi-in-latex And 1 inch is 72.27 pt.

Comment: BTW, one can use `\ht\graph`, `\dp\graph` and `\wd\graph` for the height, depth and width.  Saves a whole lot of `\newlength`s.